# Jquery LayerSlider, issue with space left underneeath

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using LayerSlider - The Parallax Effect Slider in my website dtraffic.biz but I am having problems with it. I have had to delete many lines of page.css so that the logo keeps in its place and now everything seems ok but I would like to reduce the space that is left between de LayerSlider and the next section (the one that says: member and advertisers).

Any suggestion?

Note:
My website is designed in php, it has a two files distributing the desing on the homepage, layout_header.php and layout_footer.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your css

> .dim {  margin-bottom: -40px; }

This will adjust the space below the dim div which is containing the slider.

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved my problem. Now if it's not an inconvinient I would like the slider's controller (play/pause rectangle) to disappear so that both areas fit together. I don't care if I can't pause the animation I think I can set up bigger delays and that stuff so that it fulfills my needs. Thanks for your help

Comment: Use .ls-bottom-nav-wrapper {dislay:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a -ve (negative) `margin-top` to `<div class="bc-w2">` in your CSS